# NextJS router.push weird link

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL0gx.jpg

When i try to redirect to home page after a login (or redirect to login after trying to access page without tokens) this url gets all weird.

How can i prevent that and have a normal path in the url?

```
router.push({
  pathname: "/",
  query: { redirect: router.asPath },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing the query parameter, the problem was solved.